# Heroku Postgres Maintenance change env var and break the app

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres

I deployed a NodeJS application to Heroku and attach to it a Postgres database with Heroku Postgres addons, all was working perfectly.
After a few hours, I was unable to authenticate my application. After checking the logs, I understand that the application is unable to connect to the database because of a wrong password.
After that, I also got 2 emails from Heroku that alert me of the maintenance.

So I checked the credentials database and the credentials are all the same except the URI.
I also checked on my env vars and I saw that Heroku added 2 more variables HEROKU_DATABASE_URL and HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CRIMSON_URL, I tried to edit them with the new URI of the updated Database but do have permission ...

I also tried to delete and recreate a new database but every time the Heroku Maintenance come back and break my app

Here is my connection code to Postgres (using nest js)

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const isProduction = configService.get('STAGE') === 'prod';

    return {
      ssl: isProduction,
      extra: {
        ssl: isProduction ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : null,
      },
      type: 'postgres',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
      host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
      port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
      username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
      password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
      database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
    };
  },
}),
```

Here is the error i get

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] password authentication failed for user
> "ryooypezxslwmn"

Comment: "I tried to edit them with the new URI"—the `DATABASE_URL` variable _is_ the new database URL. The `CRIMSON` variable is likely the old database URL. Why are you trying to change them? Do you use `DATABASE_URL` when you connect to Postgres? Please show us your connection code.

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Postgres [provides and maintains *one* environment variable per provisioned database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres):

> As part of the provisioning process, a `DATABASE_URL` config var is added to your app’s configuration. `DATABASE_URL` contains the URL your app uses to access the database. If your app already has a Heroku Postgres database and you’ve provisioned another one, this config var’s name instead has the format `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>_URL` (for example, `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL`).

When your database connection string needs to change, Heroku automatically updates the `DATABASE_URL` and `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>_URL` variables.

But you aren't using these variables. The `DB_HOST`, `DB_PORT`, etc., environment variables aren't set by Heroku, and Heroku won't update them for you. Rather than manually setting those variables, I *strongly* urge you to use the variables Heroku provides:

> The value of your app’s `DATABASE_URL` config var can change at any time. Do not rely on this value either inside or outside your Heroku app.

I'm not familiar with TypeORM, but it looks like [you can pass it a `url` directly](https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#postgres--cockroachdb-data-source-options):

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const isProduction = configService.get('STAGE') === 'prod';

    return {
      ssl: isProduction,
      extra: {
        ssl: isProduction ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : null,
      },
      type: 'postgres',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
      url: configService.get('DATABASE_URL'),  // <-- here
    };
  },
}),
```